# Android: Manage application execution

Tags: android

I want to make startup cleaner application for Android 1.6. My query is how to manage application that starts while phone boot or starts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I *may* be wrong but I don't believe you're going to be able to do this in the way described. You could certainly kill off apps that area already running [with the appropriate permissions] but I don't think there's any way to manage when other apps start due to the individual sandbox-style architecture - At least not without rooting the phone

Comment: Couldn't you run a service that polls looking for them?

Comment: @user432209 - Yes you could but you won't be able to find them until after they've already started - so you're either going to be polling continuously (ie kill battery life) or a significant period of time (in cpu terms) will have elapsed before you see the process - and if the first thing the app does is something you don't like, you're gambling on being able to detect it and kill it fast enough - which is risky and imprecise.